# Преобразование DateTime в DateTime2 C# LinqToDB Mapping

Tags: c#, mapping, linq2db

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой для меня непонятной ситуацией:

Имеется небольшой класс:

```
[Table(Schema = "dbo", Name = "test")]
public sealed class Test
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    public int id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Дата записи
    /// </summary>
    [Column("date"), NotNull]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Затем использую этот класс, чтобы получить данные:

```
using var db = _db();

var resultQuery = db.Test
   .Where(x => x.Date == date);

return resultQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

Если посмотреть на то, что сгенерировалось, то получаю вот такое:

```
DECLARE @date_1 DateTime2
SET     @date_1 = '2022-06-14T11:05:05.5530000'

SELECT
    [x].[id],
    [x].[date]
FROM
    [dbo].[test] [x]
WHERE
    [x].[date] = @date_1
```

**Загвоздка в том, что у меня в БД не DateTime2, а обычное DateTime и как следствие, он ничего не находит**

Пробовал определять свойство, как:

```
[Column("date", DataType = DataType.DateTime), NotNull]
```

Результат не изменился

UPD: описание таблицы Test

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Данные в таблице:

```
id  date
1   2022-06-14 11:05:05.553
2   2022-06-14 12:03:56.541
3   2022-06-14 14:05:74.724
```

Comment: а что вы хотите сравнить, делая так: .Where(x => x.Date == date)  ? описание таблицы test вы не представили, данные из неё тоже. Если вам нужно сравнение только по дате (без времени), то прямым сравнением вы не решите вопрос, нужно преобразовывать сравниваемые значения или используйте between

Comment: какой EF вы используете? посмотрите DbFunctions.

Comment: Я так понимаю, linq2db следует правильным рекомендациями и автоматически использует datetime2. | Можно попробовать точность указать, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65396950/5045688) в ответах. | Возможно, придётся маппинг сделать в MappingSchema. | В конце концов, можно на rsdn спросить - там разрабы linq2db тусуются. Хотя и здесь бывают.

Comment: @Konst - это не EF. Это linq2db - крутейшая ORM. Но, как мы видим, проблемы везде бывают.